# Balanced Branching Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graph, tree, binary-tree

So I am doing a school task that looks like this

[image]

and I have absolutely no idea where to even start. Could someone point me in the right direction?

My idea of a starting point would be to calculate the discrepancy value of the root node first (the absolute value of the sum of the leaf values given) and then (somehow) check if there exists a discrepancy value higher than the root value, if not, the root value is the minimum possible discrepancy of the input. Am I on the right track? Currently I can't seem to get any further than this.

> Important note: The tree that is built must "respect" the given order
>   of the values.  For instance if the input is (5, 0, 0, -5) you are not
>   allowed to build your tree by first combining the first and the last
>   items into a tree.  More formally: at every internal node, the input
>   values appearing as leaves in the left subtree of that node must all
>   come before the input values appearing as leaves in the right subtree.

Thanks!

Comment: my bad I misinterpreted the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given set a[1]...a[n], each corresponding to a leaf node, it is clear that the discrepancy of every tree is lower bounded by:

```
B(x[]) = max (abs(x[1]),...,abs(x[n]), abs(sum))
```

Where `sum`, the sum of all `x[i]`, corresponds to the weight of the root node of every tree build from the `x[i]`.

The goal here is simply to show that it is always possible to build a tree, the discrepancy of which is equal to this lower bound.

It is realized in two steps.

In a first step, if two adjacent nodes have different signs, we simply merge them. This corresponds by replacing these two nodes by a new node, the weight of which is the sum of the two weights. The absolute value of this weight is less than the maximum of the absolute values of the two input weights, therefore less than the bound. We reiterate this process until we only get nodes (a new set), the weights of which have all the same sign.

In a second step, we have to manage a set, derived from the initial one, where all weights have the same sign. The maximum node of all trees that can be created from it correspond to the top one, the weight of which is equal to the sum of all weights of current active nodes, which is equal to the sum of the initial set. This sum corresponds to a value less or equal than the lower bound.

Finally, we obtain a tree, the weights of which are all less or equal to the lower bound.

Example:

```
-1 -5 4 -2      -> merge -5 and 4
-1 -1 -2        -> all signs equal, 2nd step: the maximum node of this sub-array correspond to the sum -4
```

It is interesting to note that we obtain the same result by applying the rule in a different order:

```
-1 -5 4 -2      -> merge 4 and -2
-1 -5 2         -> merge -5 and 2
-1 -3           -> all signs equal, 2nd step: sum equals -4
```

Comment: Effectively, you have to repeat the process until all signs are equal. In all cases, the answer here is 5, I.e. the lower bound of the original set. The fact that we can obtain a new array with a lower bound and then a lower result doesn't change the original bound. The original bound *is* the discrepancy of the original set

Comment: The final answer *is* B. The tree construction is just to show that this lower bound can be obtained, as at each step, the newly created nodes all have a weight lower or equal the original bound B.

Comment: Note that bound calculation includes the sum. If the goal is only to provide the optimal value, complexity is O(n) and I can't see a particular drawback. I only try to minimize the maximum amplitude value, I don't try to further minimize the other values, except that they must remain lower than the maximum value equal to the bound.

Comment: Effectively O(n+n) = O(n) !

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that this is a convenient recursive problem: whenever you combine adjacent nodes, you reduce the problem by one node.  The problem state can be expressed entirely as a list of values and a max value; your given problem can be sent into the solution function as

```
a = [-1, -5, 4, -2]
balance(a, max(max(a), abs(min(a))))
```

More simply,

```
balance(a, 5)
```

The right-hand solution for this problem would progress as follows:

```
[-1, -5, 4, -2], 5
[-1, -1, -2], 5    * see note below
[-1, -3], 5
[-4], 5
```

- from here, the joining is immaterial, since there is no path remaining that can possibly exceed the original discrepancy of 5.

---

I suggest a semi-greedy approach: the goal is to work outward from the maximal node, and to avoid making it any worse, or to minimize the damage.
Locate the maximal node.  Also sum the sequence: we don't need to waste any time trying to avoid that unavoidable sum.  For instance, given

```
-5 1 1 -5 1 1 -5 1
```

We don't need to run screaming from the idea of dropping below -5: the total is -10, so we cannot avoid a discrepancy that high.  This may be a later fine-tuning consideration

---

To begin, look to each side of that maximal node; treat each as a sublist starting next to that node.  Search for a subsequence whose sum is of the opposite sign; if that is located, collapse it (taking that sequence as a sub-problem) and then merge it to the problem node.

For example:

```
4 -5 1 1 2 -1 -1 -6 -2 -1 2 -3 2 2
```

the discrepancy is `6`, near the middle.  Divide the sequence at that point into the two receding sub-sequences, with their running sums:

```
seq: -1 -1 2 1 1 -5 4
sum: -1 -2 0 1 ...

seq: -2 -1  2 -3  2 2
sum: -3 -3 -1 -4 -2 0
```

The left side (reversed, in order from the `-6` element) reaches a counter-balancing sum (opposite sign, so merging them will reduce the discrepancy) at the fourth element: `-1 -1 2 1` is the shortest sub-sequence with a positive sum.  Recur on `[1 2 -1 -1], 6` as a sub-problem (a sub-tree to consider).  This will return a sub-tree such as `((1 (2 -1) )-1)`, with a value of `1`.  The list of values is now:

```
4 -5 1 1 -6 -2 -1 2 -3 2 2
       ^ this is the sub-tree we just reduced.
```

**Now** we have a counter-balancing value adjacent to the largest discrepancy; this indicates that the next operation is to merge those two values:

```
4 -5 1  -5  -2 -1 2 -3 2 2
```

Continue similarly from here.  Note that the freedom to regress to a value of `6` can -- in some cases -- speed up the solution search.

Continuing in pieces, we will collapse this to

```
-1 -4     -2 -1 2 -3 2 2
```

This will progress from the right, gradually reducing ...

```
-1 -4     -2 -1 2 -3 2 2
-1 -4     -2 -1 2  -1  2
-1 -4     -2   1   -1  2
-1 -4       -1     -1  2
-1 -4       -1        1
-1 -4             0
```

Here, we have *finally* crawled back to the largest remaining value in the full list ...

```
-1 -4 0
-1 -4
-5
```

Is that enough to get you moving?

Comment: Unfortunately, I only understand about 50% of your explanation. I am starting to get lost in the second part (when you say "The left side reaches a counter-balancing sum at the fourth element. Recur on [1 2 -1 -1], 6 as a sub-problem, then merge that with -6, giving"). How do you define a "counter balancing sum" exactly? What do you mean by "merge with -6"? Do you mean "append -6 to the sublist"? Also, a bit confused about the recursion part. Does "Recur on ..." mean call `balance(a, max(max(a), abs(min(a))))` where `a=[1,2,-1,-1, -6]`?

Comment: That's great feedback!  I tried to guess at the correct level of presentation, and I went too high.  I'll rewrite this when I get some time -- not likely in the next 12 hours, but we'll see ...

Comment: +1 is of the opposite sign as -6, so you can combine them to pull the next node's value away from the maximum discrepancy.

Comment: If the running sum never changes sign, then there is no way to "balance" the value; we have to combine the values and take the more extreme value, as my example does with some of the sub-lists.